# Upload Reference File to Content ID

Tags: c#, .net

Has anyone attempted to do this?  From what I understand Google doesn't provide a .NET client library for this (the only examples I found were in Python and PHP).  The difficulty I'm having is that it seems to want a file upload and a JSON request body in the same request.  Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: I think they use multipart/related. https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart

Comment: Yeah, here's the documentation for the Content ID:  https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/references/insert but as you can see, it's pretty sparse with what you actually need to do.  The Drive API may provide a clue as to how to upload metadata with a file

Comment: Use XmlHttpRequest. var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest(); xhr.setRequestHeader(YOUR-JSON-STRING); xhr.send(file);

Comment: @FarzinKanzi You're saying put the entire JSON payload in a header?  That doesn't sound right

Comment: I think the main part of your problem is it's javascript, So you have php sample, Doesn't it help you?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi No, I'm using .NET, but I've never heard of putting a json string into a header, and also, which header would I put that in?

Comment: What do you mean 'Which header'? And i do not now if headers have length limitation or not. I used that to upload video and send the name of video only.

Comment: I'm using Content ID, I'm actually uploading an audio file, and it specifically says that the metadata has to be part of the request body.

Comment: Sorry I wrote bad codes. this is edited: xhr.setRequestHeader('json-data', 'YOUR-JSON-STRING');

Comment: @FarzinKanzi json-date? I don't know what that means.

Comment: json-data i edited that. (My english is not so good sorry)

Comment: I'll look at the upload video code, but this is not exactly that.  It's for a different API called ContentID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. In .NET (using HttpClient), you can use

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent("----------" + DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
    content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uploadReferenceRequest), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    StreamContent audioContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(buffer));
    audioContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    content.Add(audioContent);

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await this.Client.PostAsync(url, content))
    {
         string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    }
}
```

The key is to set the content type on each section of data, on the first is the "application/json" and the actual sound data is "application/octet-stream".  Hope someone else finds this useful.

Comment: This answer is an absolute life-saver, thank you so much! 
I'm not doing this in C# but was able to figure out the correct HTTP request from this.
You've saved me a serious headache.
The official documentation for this endpoint leaves a lot to be desired, and most of provided SDKs don't support it.